# What if a referee breaks the rules?

Tags: american-football, collegiate

If a referee breaks official regulations are there any corrective courses of action?

For example if a call is challenged and accepted by the ref after official review. Or more extreme if a ref decided to award 60 yards for a penalty. Clearly it's not allowed, but is there any actual process for that? Are refs technically free to do anything without challenge within the context of a game?

To be clear, I'm not referring to bad calls. I'm referring to bad procedure.

Comment: It would depend on the rules and bylaws of the specific league.  Most leagues do have a procedure for protesting a blatantly incorrect ruling that actually violates the rules.  You might continue to play the game "under protest" and fie a complaint with the league afterward.  Some official or committee within the league would review it, and could then order remedies such as replaying the game from the point of the incorrectly called play.